# How to get rid of hash in URL when redirecting?

Tags: browser, redirect

I have a page with two forms on it. Both are submitted to the original url of the page (action=""), the second one adds a  hash segment to it (action="#second-form"). When the second form is valid I want to redirect to another page for a second step, but without #second-form in the url.

Is this possible? It seems like no matter where I redirect the user to #second-form is always retained in the url (e.g. http://www.google.com/#second-form).

Comment: have you tried appending just a # to the redirected URL? that should override it.

Comment: just overwrite your action for that form using javascipt. You will have something like `document.getElementById('your_form_id').action='your_url'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try to put this on your code it works..

```
<base href="http://www.theurlyouwant.com/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Point your action to your filename of the page, instead of "".

E.g. (just a bunch of the same examples for different file names)
 action="index.html"
 action="index.asp"
 action="index.php"
 action="form.asp"
 action="form.php"